The total number of three-digit numbers, divisible by $3$, which can be formed using the digits $1, 3, 5, 8$ if repetition of digits is allowed,is

The total number of three-digit numbers, divisible by $3$, which can be formed using the digits $1, 3, 5, 8$ if repetition of digits is allowed, is

My solution:
$(1,1,1), (3,3,3), (5,5,5), (8,8,8), (5,5,8), (8,8,5),(1,3,5), (1,3,8)$
Total numbers are $22$
My doubt: Is there any best method for this type of question? for example question was about $5$ digits number using $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$

Your method is the best. I suppose that you use the rule 'abc is divisible by 3 if a+b+c is divisible by 3', so, if you have same question for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, you will say that 1,4 and 7 are equivalent, 2 and 5 are equivalent, and 3 and 6 are equivalent. So you will have a limited number of situations to analyze. Either we pick 1 number in each group, either 3 numbers from same group.

If we search for numbers divisible by 7 for example, it is much more complex.

While I generally agree with @Lourrran for small number of digits, if you want to do this for 100 digit numbers, then I'd recommend using recurrence relations. let $a_n, b_n, c_n$ be the number of $n-$digit numbers that leave a remainder of $1, 2, 0$ respectively when divided by $3$. Then we have $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 2b_n + 3 c_n$, and we can solve that system to find a solution for $a_{n+1}$.

If $3$-digit number and the digits are $1, 3 , 5, 8$
Number $3$ is in the form of $3k$, number $1$ is in the form of $3k + 1$ and numbers $5,8$ are in the form of $3k + 2$
Since sum of the digits must be in the form of $3n$ then
All the digits are in the form of $3k$ that is $1$ case, in the form of $3k + 1$ that is $1$ case and in the form of $3k + 2$ that is $2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ cases
Each digit is in different form that is $1\times 1\times 2 \times 3! = 12$ cases
Total number is $22$
If $5$-digit number and the digits are $1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7$
Number $3, 6$ are in the form of $3k$, number $1, 4, 7$ is in the form of $3k + 1$ and numbers $2, 5$ are in the form of $3k + 2$
Five digits are in the form of $3k$ that is $2^5 = 32$ cases.
Three digits are in the form of $3k$, and the others are in the form of $3k + 1$ and $3k + 2$ that is $\binom{5}{3}\times \binom{2}{1}\times 2^3 \times 3 \times 2 =960$ cases.
One digit is in the form of $3k$, two digits are in the form of $3k + 1$ and two digits are in the form of $3k + 2$ that is $\binom{5}{1}\times \binom{4}{2}\times 2 \times 3^2 \times 2^2 = 2160$ cases.
Two digits are in the form of $3k$, three digits are in the form of $3k + 1$  that is $\binom{5}{2}\times 2^2 \times 3^3  = 1080$ cases.
Two digits are in the form of $3k$, three digits are in the form of $3k + 2$  that is $\binom{5}{2}\times 2^3 \times 2^2  = 320$ cases.
Four digits are in the form of $3k + 1$ and one digit is in the form of $3k + 2$  that is $\binom{5}{4}\times 3^4 \times 2  = 810$ cases.
One digit is in the form of $3k + 1$ and four digits are in the form of $3k + 2$  that is $\binom{5}{1}\times 3 \times 2^4  = 240$ cases.
Total number is $5602$
